# Php query to print a certain selection of columns

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to run queries through MySQL and I want a query to display all columns that exist between two chosen columns but can't get it to work.

For example I have the following columns: `Name`, `Address`, `Car_Type`, `Colour`, `Mileage`, and `Engine`.

I want the columns from `Address` to `Mileage` (all inclusive) to print. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

With MySQL, you can either select all columns or specific columns. In your case:

`SELECT Address, Car_Type, Colour, Mileage FROM table;`

If you specify columns in a PHP array, you can build the query programmatically. Something like:

```
<?php
$cols = ['Name' , 'Address' , 'Car_Type' , 'Colour' , 'Mileage' , 'Engine'];

$index_start = array_search('Name', $cols);
$index_end = array_search('Mileage', $cols);

$col_list = implode(',', array_slice($cols, $index_start, $index_end-$index_start+1));

$query = "SELECT {$col_list} FROM table";
```

Comment: The way It works is I have a form which the user enters 2 different column names and that then determines the range . Ideally my query would get all columns between user entry 1 and user entry 2